# Firebase query for child with value

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase `.push()` to insert values into a ref which makes the entries have unique ID's. Later on in my code, I want to check if a child has a value equalling to a query.

Just like how the function `hasChild()` checks if any child has a key equalling to a certain query, is there a way to do the same thing but check if any child has a value equal to a query?

Comment: Show what you've already tried please. At the very least that will make it clear to us what technology you're using, but it typically also makes it a lot easier to help. Even better would be if you can package the question into a so-called [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
  DatabaseReference playlistReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    playlistReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, postSnapshot.getKey() + " KEY");
                Log.d(TAG, postSnapshot.getValue() + " VALUE");
                //Do your operations here!


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I was wondering why this looked so different than my code, then I realized it was for java or iOS while I'm doing web haha. I'll check if the `.getValue()` exists in web as well. For some reason I can't seem to find a list of available methods for the newest version of firebase, only older documentation.